# Date Conversion Function PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date

I have the following function:

```
CREATE function SEMANA_ISO (fecha date) returns text as $$ 
select to_char(fecha, 'mm-dd-yyyy');  
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

It works with:

```
Select SEMANA_ISO ('28/12/2014');
Select SEMANA_ISO ('01/01/2015');
Select SEMANA_ISO ('01/07/2015');
```

As you may see below

[image: Date]

But not with:

```
Select SEMANA_ISO ('12/31/2014');
```

It shows:

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: The value of time / date is out of range "12/31/2014"
SQL state: 22008
Hint: You may need a different configuration of "dateStyle".
Character: 20
```

Do you have any suggestion without having to change the datestyle so I can enter

```
Select SEMANA_ISO ('12/31/2014');
```

And get an output of:

```
12-31-2014
```

using just one function to "parse" all dates?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is declared to get a parameter of type `date` so you also need to pass such a value. `'12/31/2014'` is a character value, not a date.

When you pass a character literal (aka string) to the function Postgres is forced to do an *implicit* data type conversion based on the current datestyle - not something you should rely on.

If you want to call the function independently of the datestyle you need to pass a proper *date literal*, e.g. `DATE '2014-12-31'`

For more details on specifying date values, please see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT

Comment: What my issue is the fact of accepting ('28/12/2014') and the other two dates but I cannot make ('12/31/2014') using the same function. I have already worked with data types in this DBMS but my challenge is to accept that last date without changing any datestyle.
Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @MichVellve: again: `'28/12/2014'` is **not** a "date". It's string literal that is implicitly(!) *converted* to a date based on the current datestyle. Never, ever (really: never) rely on implicit data type conversion (that is true for any DBMS). You want implicit data type conversion to magically detect what you really mean - that's not possible. What about `01-05-2015`? Is that May, 1st or is that January, 5th? How is the system supposed to know? You **have** to use proper date literals (either ansi literals or using `to_date()`) if you want to avoid subtle bugs that appear randomly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want  `12/31/2014` accepted as a date `set datestyle to iso, dmy;`

if you want  `31/12/2014` accepted as a date `set datestyle to iso, mdy;`

you can't have both at the same time, else `4/1/2015` is ambiguos, and must be rejected.

Comment: I know. With the set datastyle sentence you can do so. What I wonder if it is possible to use the same function in order to accept ('12/31/2014') as the other values. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

There is [`to_date()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to input date literals with an arbitrary (given) format:

```
SELECT to_date('12/31/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date1
     , to_date('31/12/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS date2;
```

That's *"without changing any datestyle"*. Obviously, you need to provide a matching format pattern, though.

To output the same in any desired format, use [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('12/31/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS date_as_text
```

Comment: @MichVellve: Because 'YYYY-MM-DD' is the default (ISO 8601) format, which is used to represent a date value in textual output in Postgres. To get a string of a different format use `to_char()`. I'll add an example above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I just tried with '12/31/2014' and worked but when I enter SELECT to_char(to_date('28/12/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS date_as_text it shows: "15/04/2016" Where does this text come from?

Comment: @MichVellve: you ***cannot*** automate the process. Strings like '02/03/2014' are ambiguous, so you need to either interpret them all according to the same pattern or provide the matching pattern manually. Needs to be `to_date('28/12/2014', 'DD` **`/MM`** `/YYYY')` then.